# Jest testing crash with react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, flux, jestjs

All was good, but then add react-router in component, test crashed.

Now i just trying to require component like:

```
const component = require('path').default;
```

and see error:

```
TypeError: (0 , _useQueries2.default)(...) is not a function
```

but then i comment this:

```
import {Link} from 'react-router';
```

everything is good.

Comment: For now i try to require  {Link} from 'react-router' in test and have same error. what is wrong?